# General solution to a curve passing through a quadratic function

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus

I have the following equation:
$$\int x \, \Bbb dx = \int \Bbb dy.$$
Integrating, we get:
$$\frac{x^2}{2} + C = y + D.$$
Now, suppose I have a point $(x_0, y_0)$ in the plane. How do I find the equation of the above curve that passes through this point? I believe that I would need $2$ points for the equation so how about we consider $(0, y_1)$? Now how would I find the equation of the quadratic curve that passes through both points?

I am getting confused with the example: $\int c \, \Bbb dx = \int \Bbb dy$. Solving this equation is just the equation of a line. So to find the equation that passes through the point $(x_0, y_0)$, we have: $$c(x-x_0) = y-y_0.$$ The difference I see algebraically, is that in the first example, I add the $C$ and $D$ whereas in the second example I subtract $x_0$ and $y_0$. I would guess that these negative signs do not even matter, as long as one is consistent of course.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: You can think of $D-C$ as begin one constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need one point:

Let $(x_0,y_0)$ be this point and consider the equation $y= \frac{x^2}{2}+C$. Plug in $y_0=\frac{x_0^2}{2}+C$ to find $C$ in terms of $x_0$ and $y_0$. This uniquely determines your equation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you’re asking, shouldn’t you be able to substitute $x_0$ and $y_0$ into the equation of the curve and solve for the constant $C - D$? This is true because even in the linear example, you just substituted the point into the equation, solved for the constant, and then re-substituted the constant into the original equation. So if you performed the same process on the quadratic, you would get
$$
y_0 = \frac{x_0^2}{2} + C - D
\\ C - D = y_0 - \frac{x_0^2}{2}
\\ y = \frac{x_0^2}{2} + y_0 - \frac{x_0^2}{2}
$$
And finally:
$$
 y - y_0 = \frac{x^2 - x_0^2}{2}
$$